# Help in Create Page like "aspx?id=1"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write a code that open a new page in for ex : ".aspx?id=1" .
like this site :

```
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=76
```

when my user click on his article then go to "aspx?id=76" 
what am i going to do ?
thanks in Advance .

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What do you need exactly to do? The ?id=1 variable is accessible from Request.QueryString collection, then you can process it the way you like.

Comment: i want when a user click on my link "bla.apsx" then click on a Article Then go to "bla.aspx?id=2"

Comment: Are you asking how to make the link itself?  Or in a more general sense how to make a dynamic website that does things like bind a repeater to a list of records to create links to individual pages for those records?  As it stands, this question is very broad and vague.

Comment: have you ever used query strings in the asp.net application?

Comment: It doesn't sound like Eva knows anything about ASP.net from the way the question is worded.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = this.Request["id"];
```